# Virtaul machines on Intel Xeon e5420 cpu

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, central-processing-unit, intel

I google around to find out how many cores in intel xeon e5420 cpu, but not got the actual answer.

I have intel xeon e5420 cpu, I would like to run multiple virtual machines with 2 cores on each, how many Virtual machine I can have? Please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [top google result for `xeon e5420`](http://ark.intel.com/products/33927/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5420-12M-Cache-2_50-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB0)  answers you #cores question as  do most if not all of the first page of results including the amazon pages. I don't see how you failed to see that.

Answer (score 3):

The Intel Xeon E5420 CPU has 4 cores, as clearly documented [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/33927/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5420-12M-Cache-2_50-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB0); it doesn't support hyperthreading, thus it can run a maximum of 4 concurrent threads.

This of course doesn't mean *anything* in terms of how many virtual machines it can run, because this strongly depends on what the VMs are actually *doing*, not on how many vCPUs you allocate to them.